# Swift range check > in switch

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, swift5, nsrange

The following code doesn't compile in Swift. What is the best way to alternatively express it?

```
   //f1 & f2 are float vars between 0 & 1

   switch value {
            case 0...f1:
                break
            case >f1..f1+f2:
                break
            case >f1+f2..<=1:
                break
            default:
                break
            }
```

Comment: I'm trying to duplicate the error because you haven't included it. Could you post enough for that? Specifically, `value` may be a bad name for a local variable. Maybe, if possible, let me know the *exact* build error?

Comment: What are you trying to express with the switch statement? What is `>f1..f1+f2` and `>f1+f2..<=1` supposed to mean?

Comment: I want the second case to be matched strictly for cases in the interval (f1, f1+f2] with f1 not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create a range in Swift that is open on the low end.

This will accomplish what you intended:

```
switch value {
case 0...f1:
    print("one")
case f1...(f1 + f2):
    print("two")
case (f1 + f2)...1:
    print("three")
default:
    print("four")
}
```

Since `switch` matches the first `case` it finds, you don't have to worry about being non-inclusive on the low end.  `f1` will get matched by the `"one"` case, so it doesn't matter that the `"two"` case also includes it.

If you wanted to make the first case exclude `0`, you could write it like this:

```
case let x where 0...f1 ~= x && x != 0:
```

**or**

```
case let x where x > 0 && x <= f1:
```